# XML Entity for "/"?

Tags: xml, entity, escaping, sequence

So I'm writing some XML generating code, and found that the following attribute value was screwing up the XML formatting:

```
"Jim/Bob"
```

So I looked into the XML Entities used as escape sequences and every list I saw did not include one for the forward slash.  Am I missing something obvious here? Seems like the sort of thing you'd want to escape...

Comment: Can you define "screwing up"?  What code are you using to create the XML.

Comment: Ok so it turns out it wasn't the / after all it was the  "&" in another attribute on the same line. That explains why there's no escape sequence for it!

Comment: In retrospect this question was pretty stupid, if anyone has the rep to remove it or close it.. they should!

Comment: +1 @Alpants Keep it open, google brought me here first result, and the answers are helpful

Comment: I hit a case where an unescaped forward slash caused a seeming issue in XSLT:  <xsl:value-of select="Jim/Bob"/>   This tried to run an XPath expression which, of course, failed.  I realized that I simply needed to wrap it in single quotes for it to work: <xsl:value-of select="'Jim/Bob'"/>  I comment this only because my (dumb) issue led me to this page before I figured it out.

Comment: I too assumed / would mess up my XML, so the question was useful

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The forward slash is valid as is and does not need further encoding.

The only reserved characters are:

```
>
<
&
%
```

For even more XML entities - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: ‘%’ does not need encoding in XML. ‘>’ can need encoding in one particular niche situation. ‘"’ or ‘'’ will need encoding inside attribute values (whichever was used as the delimiter for that attribute).

Comment: Nope. No magic, no nothing. Nothing helped me in my case. Only `formatted="false"` solved it for me.

Comment: Some text editors render characters which appear to be fine, but when opening it in a different editor, you can see the the character is actually an illegal character.  I had a situation where I copied text including an em-dash (the long hyphen) from MS Word into an XML file in Notepad. Looks fine there but the XML ends up being invalid.  Looking at the file in Visual Studio Code, the em-dash was rendered as an invalid character (was diamond with question mark in it). So re-copied the text into Visual Studio Code and re-saved and the file retained the valid em-dash character.  Go figure.

Answer (score 9):

I know it turned out this wasn't the problem, but I thought it would be helpful to mention that, in addition to bobince's answer, the **Fraction Slash** HTML entity `&frasl;` looks [just like a forward slash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2044/index.htm). Just in case anybody reaching this page actually *does* want an HTML entity for something representing a forward slash.

Comment: The SAX parser was giving me errors about an entity referenced but not declared, using &frasl; so I used the Unicode equivalent &#8260; and it works great. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed @Lambart, I wasn't that specific; you'll need to use the `&#8260;` entity in XML, which is naturally also valid HTML, but in HTML you have the additional convenience of using the more easily remembered `&frasl;` HTML entity.

Comment: @bobince has suggested &#47; but there is &sol; as well

Answer (score 8):

I don't think the comments in this thread are entirely correct since if you use a schema (XSD) you could define elements with names Jim, Bob and Jim/Bob without any issues. But then when you want to define the element and entity:

```
<names>
  <Jim>Carrey</Jim>
  <Bob>Jones</Bob>
  <Jim/Bob>Six figured Hillbilly</Jim/Bob>
</names>
```

The problems are obvious.

Comment: Thanks. This is the problem I was having. I needed to replace a bunch of invalid xml element characters with valid substitutes.

Answer (score 7):

FYI although a slash is valid XML, watch out how it's being used downstream. We used it for connecting to an azure service bus queue. Azure itself generated keys with slashes in the connection strings, but then broke silently when we tried to use them. Escaping them with `“&#47;”` made it work

```
"Jim&#47;Bob"
```

Answer (score 6):

There's no predefined entity reference for it, but you can use a character reference: “&#47;”.

However, you don't need to escape / for inclusion in XML. You might have to include it for inclusion in something else, for example a URI path part. But then you'd have to escape it for that format first; the application that picks up the URI wouldn't have any way to know if you'd encoded it in the XML or not.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see why a value of "Jim/Bob" would need escaping or cause XML any problems at all.

Answer (score -1):

You probably have a constrained attribute, as defined in the XML Schema.

I do not know what you mean by XML formatting.