# DOM Parser : How to handle special characters

Tags: parsing, dom, xml-parsing

I have a Webservice(API) which I am passing to the DOM parser and it give the parsed result

Code reference :

```
public void parseContent(){
  URL url = new URL(http://My_Webservice_API);
  URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
  con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
  con.setReadTimeout(5000);
  Document doc = null;
  DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
  doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(con.getInputStream()));
  doc.getDocumentElement().normalize ();
  NodeList TC = doc.getElementsByTagName("root");
  m_cTotalNo = TC.getLength();
  System.out.println("Total no of elements : " + m_cTotalNo);
}
```

Every thing works fine. The parser breaks on `"<element>5>7</element>  "` . Please put some light how to handle the special character.

Comment: No idea, it reminds me of Java and it looks *horrible*. Not the syntax itself, but the numerous hoops you have to jump through to do a pretty basic task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The forward slash is valid as is and
>   does not need further encoding.
>
> The only reserved characters are:
>
> `>` `<` `&` `%`

[XML Entity for "/"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539143/xml-entity-for/539158#539158)

If the parser *really* breaks on this (and not on some other character), then that is a bug.

You should encode `>` as `&gt;` in XML.

Answer (score 0):

try escaping those characters with a backslash: "\"

example: `"5\/7"` in your element's contents

Comment: Backslashes do not escape in XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that buy using XPL, which is just like XML except it allows XML's "special characters" in text elements. If you need the full power of XML processing, you can use the XPL parser to pre-process. The following article explains doing the preprocessing without any performance loss (Java Concurrency). [Artificial Intelligence, XML, and Java Concurrency](http://java.dzone.com/articles/artificial-intelligence-xml)