# Kettle 'XML Output' step changing / to &#47;

Tags: xml, url, pentaho, kettle

I am trying to output xml to file using Kettle, but it is changing my URLs from:

```
http://test.com
```

to:

```
http:&#47;&#47;test.com
```

Any idea how to prevent the url from changing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i know this behaviour, i solved using the "output to file" step instead "output to xml" step. Before this step add a a new step called new xml, and output the xml row to the "final output to file" step.  This should works.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539143/xml-entity-for), there is no general requirement for `/` to be encoded but `&#47;` is the correct escape code for it, so Kettle's behavior is not appear to be necessary here. Looking at what you can set in the step, the only thing that seems like it might be related to this is the encoding of the text written out in the XML file. I don't know what you have it set on now but you might need to try a different encoding to avoid this problem.

Failing that, I would contact Pentaho on the forums or file a bug because there does not seem to be a good reason for this behavior.