# Pentaho Kettle to handle special characters in XML output

Tags: xml, csv, character-encoding, pentaho, kettle

I have a CSV file with the following fields and data.

```
type,
state,
priority,
headline,

Defect,
Closed,
Very High,
Hello|World|data | this|has|problem,
```

when I use XML output, the resultant XML for tag headline becomes

`<headline>Hello&#x7c;World&#x7c;data &#x7c; this&#x7c;has&#x7c;problem</headline>` under UTF-8 encoding.

what should i do to get output as

```
 `<headline>Hello|World|data | this|has|problem</headline>`
```

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question originally. You're asking how to get the XML output step to quit replacing the '|' characters with &#x7c, right? Well, I can't replicate your problem. I read in your CSV data and wrote it to an XML output, and all is well. There must be something else going on. Can you post your whole transform?

Comment: You want do decode the HTML entity? Maybe use the JavaScript-Step in Kettle with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796718/html-entity-decode

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635242/kettle-xml-output-step-changing-to-47/13648934#13648934

Answer (score 0):

You may add a String Operations step to your stream and apply a Unescape HTML to this result and you'll get the desired result.