# replace forwardslash in xmlparser javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

i have one xml variable that contains forwardslash .Now am trying to parse to string using xmlparser.parseFromString(xmlval ,"text/xml")

```
**var xmlval = < name > forward/slash/error < /name >**
  var result = xmlparser.parseFromString(xmlval ,"text/xml")
```

Getting syntax error because of forwardslash. How can i solve the problem ?

Comment: can you add in the actual xml you're working with? or at least a part of it? I doubt that the forward slash should cause any issues in parsing the xml.

Comment: @RezaKarami yes the forward slash only cause the error

Comment: The forward slash is not a reserved character for xml, read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/539158/4266776

Comment: in your question, the `xmlval` isn't wrapped as string. If that's intended then that's your problem. Otherwise the parser should handle it without problems